# Неверное отображение списка

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть список из картинок. Работаю с фрэймворком bootstrap. Есть список изображений к нему прописаны стили,которые не срабатывают, а так же col-3 
Вот сайт.  http://37.195.222.8/web-nsk/ . [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
ul.example{
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
  .example image{
    height: 500px;
  }
```

```html
        <ul class="example ">
         <li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"</li></img>
         <li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"</li></img>
         <li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"</li></img>
         <li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"</li></img>
         <li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"</li></img>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Все хорошо работает, у вас не хватает родителя. Если хотите сделать родителя с классом row, назначьте его ul и col-3 вешайте на li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот если вы сделаете родителя как row и li как сol будет как на скринах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Блин, я забыл это написать. Из-за такой глупости ломал себе мозг. Спасибо

Comment: Ошибку которую указывают люди тоже нужно править тег img не закрывается другим тегом, он закрывается в себе `<img ... />`

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибка в HTML коде

```
<li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"</li></img>
```

заменить на

```
<li><img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
```

Comment: И ничего не поменяется?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .example image{
> ```
>
> ```
> <img class="col-3" src="slide1.jpg"
> ```

Естественно не применяется, имя тега ведь другое.

И ещё символ `>` потерялся.